# Change the value of Component via ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Material-UI with React

I have Slider and want to set the value.

```
class ParamBoard extends React.Component{
   constructor(props) {
     this.sliderRef =  React.createRef();
   }
   componentDidMount() {
     this.sliderRef.current.value = 1 // not work.
   }
   this.hugaRef = React.createRef();
    render(){
      return (
        <Slider step={1} min={1} max={6} marks width={1/4 } ref="{this.sliderRef}" 
       aria-labelledby="continuous-slider" />)
       )
    }
}
```

Normally with jQuery I do like this ('#myslider').value(2) to get the dom and change the value.

However in Reactjs I thought I should use `ref`??? is it correct or how can I fix this ??

Comment: 1. use state, 2. ref is a string in your case, you should remove the double quotes

Comment: Why are you trying to use a react ref to set the initial slider value versus using react state 
 and `value` prop or specifying the `defaultValue` prop? What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DrewReese I want to set the defaulut value from cookie so I want to se the `componentDidMount()` in componentDidMount

Comment: @Nishant Oh That's true.... I should use `state` I was a bit confused.